# Centre of mass Polar Coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I have the following question:
[image]

So I've established that the centre of mass for $x$ is $$x=\frac{(1-\alpha^2)}{\pi(1-\alpha)} $$
and $y$ is the same. My thought to prove the centre of mass was outside was to use that it would be outside if $$x^2+y^2<\alpha^2$$ meaning (since x=y) that $2x^2=(\frac{(1-\alpha^2)}{\pi(1-\alpha)})^2<\alpha^2 $. But I can't get this to work. I feel like I'm missing something obvious..

Comment: You forgot to multiply by $2$ in LHS of the last inequality. Btw, the fraction for the coordinates simplifies to $\frac{1+\alpha}{\pi}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you got $x$ right, you can simplify it as

$$x=\frac{1-\alpha^2}{\pi(1-\alpha)}=\frac{(1-\alpha)(1+\alpha)}{\pi(1-\alpha)}=\frac{1+\alpha}{\pi}$$

Now,

$$x^2+y^2=2\frac{(1+\alpha)^2}{\pi^2} < \alpha^2 $$
$$2(1+\alpha)^2<\pi^2\alpha^2$$
$$2(1+\alpha)^2-\pi^2\alpha^2<0$$
$$(2-\pi^2)\alpha^2+4\alpha+2<0$$
$$(\pi^2-2)\alpha^2-4\alpha-2>0$$

A parabola with positive coefficient at $\alpha^2$ (we use that $\pi^2>2$) is  positive **outside** its roots, of which we'll calculate the bigger one:

$$D=4^2-4\cdot(-2)\cdot(\pi^2-2)=16+8(\pi^2-2)=8\pi^2$$
$$\alpha=\frac{4+\sqrt{D}}{2(\pi^2-2)}=\frac{4+2\sqrt{2}\pi}{2(\pi^2-2)}=
\frac{2+\sqrt{2}\pi}{\pi^2-2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}(\pi+\sqrt{2})}{(\pi+\sqrt 2)(\pi - \sqrt 2)} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi-\sqrt{2}}$$

This means the former inequality ($x^2+y^2<\alpha^2$) is satisfied if $\alpha > \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi-\sqrt{2}}$.

---

The inequality is also satisfied if $\alpha$ is less then the smaller root, which equals

$$\frac{4-\sqrt{D}}{2(\pi^2-2)}=\frac{4-2\sqrt{2}\pi}{2(\pi^2-2)}=
\frac{2-\sqrt{2}\pi}{\pi^2-2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}(\pi-\sqrt{2})}{(\pi+\sqrt 2)(\pi - \sqrt 2)} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi+\sqrt{2}}$$

So, for $\alpha \in \bigg[0, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi+\sqrt{2}} \bigg)$ the center of mass is also outside.